# Definition of "tenor" argument in QuantLib's Schedule class object

Tags: quantlib

In **QuantLib** an object of class [**`Schedule`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_schedule.html) takes const [**`Period`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_period.html) `&tenor` as argument.

I would like to know what that `tenor` is supposed to be.

Let I would like to price a floating rate bond (that is, to use the `Schedule` object as argument for [**`FloatingRateBond`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_floating_rate_bond.html) object) which pays quarterly EURIBOR every **two** months: from what I've read so far, the quarterly EURIBOR (forward) rate is set through an [**`IborIndex`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_ibor_index.html) class object while I'm not sure of how I can set the payment frequency.

Maybe I should use that `Schedule` argument (`tenor = "2M"` here)?

P.S.: in order to avoid too many questions regarding **QuantLib** here, I'm looking for some reference which explain topics like the one of this question, that is, the natural language definition of classes' and methods' arguments. Can you suggest me any source suitable to this purpose?

Comment: Try Period(Bimonthly) as parameter it means every second month, wilmott forums could be a good source of reference.

Comment: Then what's the `tenor` argument of `Schedule`?

Comment: it is the frequency of the schedule (e.g. monthly, bimonthly, annual, quarterly...)

Comment: Uhmm... I guess it's not really clear to me what `Schedule` is. Doesn't a `Schedule` object states all the "temporal" elements of a bond? Let you have a bond like the UCGIM Float 10/31/13 ~ IT0004416886 (this one pays quarterly EURIBOR): if you had to price it via **QuantLib**, what the `tenor` argument of `Schedule` would be equal to? Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tenor* is just a different term for *time to maturity*. A schedule is generated from *startDate* and *endDate* in combination with a time to maturity and some info on calendar specifics.

Here is an example from Dimitri Reiswich' Presentation from [quantlib.com](http://quantlib.org/slides/dima-ql-intro-1.pdf), I hope it makes the use of schedule clearer to you:

```
void testingSchedule1 (){
Date begin (30 , September ,2009) , end (15 , Jun ,2012);
Calendar myCal = Japan ();
BusinessDayConvention bdC= BusinessDayConvention ( Following );
Period myTenor (6, Months );
DateGeneration :: Rule myRule = DateGeneration :: Forward ;
Schedule mySched (begin ,end , myTenor ,myCal ,bdC ,bdC , myRule , true );
std :: vector <Date > finalSched = mySched . dates ();
BOOST_FOREACH ( Date d, finalSched ) std :: cout << d << std :: endl ;
}
```

which generates the following dates:

```
September 30th, 2009
March 31st, 2010
September 30th, 2010
March 31st, 2011
September 30th, 2011
March 30th, 2012
June 15th, 2012
```

As you can see, your assumption is actually right - the schedule contains all the payment dates. The Input you need to give it simply

```
Period myTenor (2, Months );
```

---

**General info on classes**

If you are looking for something that specifically deals with design patterns for finance, I recommend [Mark Joshis Book on that topic](http://www.amazon.de/Patterns-Derivatives-Pricing-Mathematics-Finance/dp/0521721628/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1379541249&sr=8-1&keywords=mark%20joshi). But, be warned, its pretty hard for C++ Newbies, the finance part is actually quite easy. Otherwise, I think you should look into *Design Patterns* in general, unfortunately the only book I've actually read about those is the Heads First book, I really cannot recommend those provided you're older than 12.

Comment: Thank you, phi. If I'm right, this means that a bond which pays quarterly EURIBOR every 2 months requires an `IborIndex` object whose `tenor` is equal to `3M` for what regards the floating rate and a `Schedule` object whose `tenor` is equal to `2M` for what regards the payment frequency.